# JavaScript/krajeeDialog.alert seems to be faulty in GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, kartik-v

My intention is getting alert message, if checkBox in GridView has been activated. Unfortunately, I will get nothing, neither an error nor message. What’s wrong with this code. Action in Controller actually will do its job, JavaScript will do its job for $search, **for $checkBox** it will **not** do its job. 
**Rephrasing for Muhammad Omer Aslam(Here is complete View code)**

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\alert\Alert;
use yii\web\Session;

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Kunde');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
$js = <<<JS
        $('.search-button').click(function(){
             $('.search-form').toggle(1000);
             return false;
        });
        $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
            $('form[name=\"idKunde\"]').on('click', '#cb input[type=\'checkbox\']', function(){
                 if($(this).is(':checked')){
                     krajeeDialog.alert('Implementieren Sie die Stapelmails über den entsprechenden Button.');
                 }
            });
        });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
?>
<?php
//Hier werden alle Flashnachrichten ausgegeben
$session = new Session();
foreach ($session->getAllFlashes() as $flash) {
    foreach ($flash as $ausgabe) {
        echo Alert::widget([
            'type' => Alert::TYPE_INFO,
            'title' => 'Information',
            'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign',
            'body' => $ausgabe,
            'showSeparator' => true,
            'delay' => false
        ]);
    }
}
?>
<div class="kunde-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <div class="search-form" style="display:none">
        <?= $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    </div>
    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Advance Search'), '#', ['class' => 'btn btn-info search-button']) ?>
    </p>
    <!-- hier wird das HTMl-Formular, welches die Mailmethode im Controller aufruft, implementiert-->
    <?=
    Html::beginForm(['/kunde/send'], 'post', ['name' => 'idKunde']);
    ?>
    <?php
    $gridColumn = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'width' => '50px',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_expand', ['model' => $model]);
            },
            'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'expandOneOnly' => true
        ],
        ['attribute' => 'id', 'visible' => false],
        [
            'attribute' => 'l_plz_id',
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Plz'),
            'value' => function($model, $id) {
                return $model->l_plz_id ? $model->lPlz->plz : null;
            },
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'geschlecht',
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Geschlecht'),
            'value' => function($model, $id) {
                return $model->geschlecht ? $model->geschlecht0->typus : null;
            },
        ],
        'vorname',
        'nachname',
        'stadt',
        'strasse',
        [
            'attribute' => 'geburtsdatum',
            'format' => 'html',
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Geburtsdatum'),
            'value' => function($model, $id) {
                if ($model->geburtsdatum) {
                    $expression = new yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
                    $now = (new \yii\db\Query)->select($expression)->scalar();
                    $diff = strtotime($now) - strtotime($model->geburtsdatum);
                    $hours = floor($diff / (60 * 60));
                    $year = floor($hours / 24 / 365);
                    $output = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($model->geburtsdatum)) . '<br>' . $year . " Jahre alt";
                    return $output;
                } else {
                    return NULL;
                }
            },
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
            'attribute' => 'solvenz',
            'trueLabel' => 'Ja',
            'falseLabel' => 'Nein',
            'label' => 'Ist Solvent',
            'encodeLabel' => false,
        ],
        /*
          [
          'attribute' => 'bankverbindung_id',
          'label' => Yii::t('app', 'BankverbindungID'),
          'value' => function($model) {
          if ($model->bankverbindung) {
          return $model->bankverbindung->id;
          } else {
          return NULL;
          }
          },
          'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
          'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(\backend\models\Bankverbindung::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'id'),
          'filterWidgetOptions' => [
          'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
          ],
          'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Bankverbindung', 'id' => 'grid-kunde-search-bankverbindung_id']
          ],
         */
        [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn', 'checkboxOptions' => function($model) {
                return ['value' => $model->id];
            },
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{bankverbindung},{termin}',
            'buttons' => [
                'bankverbindung' => function ($id, $model) {
                    if (!empty($model->bankverbindung_id)) {
                        $pk = backend\models\Bankverbindung::findOne(['id' => $model->bankverbindung_id])->id;
                        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>', ['/bankverbindung/view', 'id' => $pk], ['title' => 'Bankverbindung anzeigen']);
                    }
                },
                'termin' => function ($id, $model) {
                    $data = frontend\models\Adminbesichtigungkunde::find()->all();
                    foreach ($data as $item) {
                        if ($item->kunde_id == $model->id) {
                            $fk = $item->besichtigungstermin_id;
                            $link = \Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl . '/termin_viewen';
                            $link .= '?id=' . $fk;
                            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span>', $link, ['title' => 'zum Termin im Frontend springen']);
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
        ],
    ];
    ?>
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'filterSelector' => '.choiceRadio',
        'columns' => $gridColumn,
        'pjax' => true,
        'pjaxSettings' => [
            'neverTimeout' => true,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'style' => 'overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'
        ],
        'condensed' => true,
        'responsiveWrap' => true,
        'hover' => true,
        'persistResize' => true,
        'panel' => [
            'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
            "heading" => "<h3 class='panel-title'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-globe'></i> " . $this->title . "</h3>",
            'after' => Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i> Reset Grid', ['/kunde/index'], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'title' => 'Setzt die GridView zurück']),
            'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10],
        ],
        'toolbar' => [
            ['content' =>
                Html::submitButton('<span class=" fa fa-pencil-square-o">', ['', 'class' => 'btn btn-success', 'title' => 'implementiert Mails für ausgewählte Kunden', 'name' => 'button_checkBoxes', 'data' => ['pjax' => '1']])
            ],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}'
        ],
        'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10],
    ]);
    ?>

</div>
<?=
Html::endForm();
?>
```

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Comment: won't fix problem. same result: action for $('.search-button'), but no action for 'ready pjax:success'

Comment: show the updates you added to your code, by editing your answer

Comment: and please add complete code for the view file you are using

Comment: sorry i, didnt had time previously, will look into it today

Comment: Okay. Hope, U'll find bug in my code having been rephrased

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't throwing any errors on the console and doing nothing just try changing

```
$this->registerJs($checkBox);
```

with

```
$this->registerJs($checkBox,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

#### Things to Pay Attention

- You need to change the selector `$(idKunde).click`, the `idKunde` should be a string whereas you are not using quotes around it when binding the click so it will be parsing as a variable `idKunde` instead of the string.
- Above all, you have defined `idKunde` as `name` for the form and not `id`.

  ```
  <?=
      Html::beginForm(['/kunde/send'], 'post', ['name' => 'idKunde']);
  ?>
  ```
- So the selector should be like `form[name="idKunde"]`.
- You should use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) rather than a simple string for such snippets.
- And use a single `registerJs()` call rather than calling twice.

Change your javascript code to below

```
$js =<<<JS
        $('.search-button').click(function(){
             $('.search-form').toggle(1000);
             return false;
        });
        $('form[name=\"idKunde\"]').on('click', '#cb input[type=\'checkbox\']', function(){
             if($(this).is(':checked')){
                 krajeeDialog.alert('Implementieren Sie die Stapelmails über den entsprechenden Button.');
             }
        });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

**EDIT:**

As you are binding the click to the checkboxes inside the `GridView` it would be better to wrap your current script inside the `pjax:success` event as when a reload is performed on the grid via filtering or changing the pagination the script won't work anymore.

So wrap the above-suggested snippet for `click` event inside the

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
// add the click event binding here
});
```

So your complete javascript snippet will look like below

```
$js =<<<JS
        $('.search-button').click(function(){
             $('.search-form').toggle(1000);
             return false;
        });
        $(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){
            $('form[name=\"idKunde\"]').on('click', '#cb input[type=\'checkbox\']', function(){
                 if($(this).is(':checked')){
                     krajeeDialog.alert('Implementieren Sie die Stapelmails über den entsprechenden Button.');
                 }
            });
        });
JS;

$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: No fixing. Same result as before: Action for '.search-button', but no action for 'ready pjax:success'